# Rails is Nuked - How to Reinstall

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've just spend about 3 hours trying to reinstall a nuked Rails installation. It stopped working after trying to install the "authlogic" gem (which, btw, if anyone has any idea how to install that, PLEASE let me know).

**NEW ERROR**

```
Justins-MacBook-Pro:cse480 Justin$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load': /Volumes/Working/cse480/config/initializers/session_store.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end (SyntaxError)
...sion_store :cookie_store, key: '_cse480_session'
                              ^
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:588
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:587
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `run_initializers'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Volumes/Working/cse480/config/environment.rb:5
    from /Volumes/Working/cse480/config.ru:4:in `require'
    from /Volumes/Working/cse480/config.ru:4
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /Volumes/Working/cse480/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from /Volumes/Working/cse480/config.ru:1
```

**OLD PROBLEM**

The steps were something like this:
1. Nuke Rails after typing "sudo gem install authlogic"
2. Try removing ~/.rvm, still doesn't work
3. Using gem uninstall, remove ALL gems until nothing shows in gem list --local
4. sudo gem install rails

Now, "rails" works, but only outside a Rails project. Whenever I go into a rails app and run rails server, I get the following:

```
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:3.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex.from_installed_gems is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::SourceIndex.from_installed_gems called from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/source.rb:166.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex.installed_spec_directories is deprecated, use Specification.dirs. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex.installed_spec_directories called from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:47.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex.from_gems_in is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::SourceIndex.from_gems_in called from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:47.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#initialize is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#initialize called from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:67.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#spec_dirs= is deprecated, use Specification.dirs=. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#spec_dirs= called from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:94.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#refresh! is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#refresh! called from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:95.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#load_gems_in is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#load_gems_in called from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:322.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#each is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#each called from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.0/lib/bundler/source.rb:166.
Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources
```

So apparently rake is gone. But only inside a Rails project (even a new one!). Both rails and rake work, but both fail if I'm cd'd to a Rails project directory.

I'm on Mac OS 10.7.3 and everything worked perfectly up until using sudo gem install authlogic.

Comment: Dude! Just leave and escape! Your project is nuked! You are in danger of being exposed to excess amounts of radioactive radiations! ESCAPE!

Comment: Now joking aside, delete your `Gemfile.lock` and run `bundle install` from within your project's root directory. Also why did you do `sudo gem`? With rvm you only need to run `gem install...`. It could be that authlogic is installed in the system-wide gem directory and not your home folder's gem directory.

Comment: This is almost certainly a case of your mixing the preinstalled ruby with your rvm installed ruby.  The beauty of rvm is that you generally don't sudo install anything.  Since you've deleted your .rvm file, you may need to reinstall rvm.

Comment: Well, I deleted `Gemfile.lock` and ran `bundle install` again, and now I get another error, which I'm going to put in the original question above. If I do the same thing to a brand new Rails project (`rails new …`) everything works fine. I've compared config.ru, environment.rb, and Gemfile between both projects and they're identical, but the original project fails with the new errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty here is likely bundler doesn't realize all these gems are gone. Try going into your Rails directory and doing 'bundle install'; this should result in all your gems returning.

Comment: Accepting this because why not.